# How to auto-detect keyboard input AND auto-focus to input AND enter it into input using js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

OK, I know how to detect keyboard input. I know how to focus on keyboard input.

But I want to know what the best practice is for detecting keyboard input => focusing to textarea or textfield => AND enter that key into the field.

Here's how it would work: I'm on a page. I type <kbd>A</kbd>. Then my textfield gets focused and <kbd>A</kbd> is typed into the field. This sounds trivial but actually I haven't found a simple way to do this. The reason is because the initial keyboard input event is not directed towards the textfield, and I need to propagate that event to the newly focused text field.

Is there a conventional approach to doing something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample html:

```
<form>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" id="thisguy" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
</form>​​​
```

jQuery for above html

```
$(document).live('keypress', function (e) {

$('#thisguy').val($('#thisguy').val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});​
```

Needs to be cleaned up. Maybe set focus instead of changing the text value.

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much how I am doing it now. I guess there is no "native" way of doing this (such as propagating the event, etc.)

Comment: .live method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers when content is dynamically added to a page.